# How can I open urls on my host machine with VMWARE?

Tags: windows-7, vmware

I am running a Windows 7 vm with  WMware player from Fedora.  I have VMWare tools installed successfully and I have successfully some of it's features like Unity mode so it seems to be installed correctly.  That being said I still cannot get urls to open up in my host machine's browsers, these are the steps I have taken:

1. Within the vm I set "Default Host Application" to be the application to open urls.
2. Within my host machine I have set Chrome to be my preferred application for opening urls.
3. Enabled Shared Folders in the vm (Not sure if that really helped anything but I saw it suggested on a forum post)

After doing that when I click on a link I get the following error message:

**Default host Application:** 
Make sure the virtual machine's configuration allows the guest to open host applications.

I cannot find any option like that in my vm's configuration so I am not sure what the error message is referring to.

Comment: This sounds like a network configuration error.  Make sure the virtual machine has access to your network device.

Comment: I can access the internet just fine so it seems to have access to my network devices.  Is there any other kind of connectivity that would be required that I could test?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by changing from "Default Host Application" set for the HTTP/HTTPS protocols in Default Programs, to "Internet Explorer".  See image:

http://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2196252-104061/Defaut-Host-Application.png

http://communities.vmware.com/message/2187234

-Joe

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The question is "How to open urls on host machine with VMWARE?", NOT how to open url locally inside the guest. This is a bad answer.